# Selecting whole text with backslashes in it

Tags: c#, select, textbox

I am creating a search program and I want do display the paths to the found files in a multiline textbox. The problem is that I want to select the whole path to a file and I can't due to presence of backslashes. How can I do that? I tried this but it doesn't work very well.

```
private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        int x = d.length_sum(path, textBox2.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox2.SelectionStart));
        int y = path[textBox2.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox2.SelectionStart)].Length + d.num_backslash(path[textBox2.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox2.SelectionStart)]);
        textBox2.Select(x, y);
        string aux = textBox2.SelectedText;
        selected_files.Add(aux);
        textBox3.Text += aux;
        textBox3.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: What is `d`? What are its methods?

Comment: Why not use the textBox.Lines property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question right, this should do:

```
private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int line = textBox2.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart);
    if (line >= 0 && line < textBox2.Lines.Length) 
        Console.WriteLine(textBox2.Lines[line]);  // or whatever you want to do with it..
}
```